# Xfce system tray tool to connect/disconnect bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth, panel, tray

I am using Xfce desktop on Ubuntu 18.04-based system.

I can easily switch *connected* audio output devices between them (including bluetooth ones) with a [Xfce panel plugin](https://askubuntu.com/a/1153251/925128), but when bluetooth speakers are not already connected I use  `blueberry` and `blueberry-tray` to access and connect bluetooth devices.

I am using various bluetooth speakers with different computers and often the speakers are not connected automatically in Linux. Using `blueberry-tray` is a bit cumbersome as it involves no less than 3 clicks and two opened windows.

[image]

`blueberry-tray` is a tray icon to start the `blueberry` GUI, not really a tray tool - one that should provide all needed operations by itself without starting a separate GUI, with multiple windows, etc.

I wonder if there is a tray tool similar to [Sound Switcher Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/977111/925128) or the aforementioned Xfce panel plugin, only not for switching connected devices, but for connecting/disconnecting available (already 'added'--associated) devices, notably bluetooth ones.

I mean something like the panel tool they have on a Mac, where you can click the icon, see all added devices - including non-connected ones -, and press 'connect' without opening any window.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[New features in Linux Mint 19.2 Xfce](https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tina_xfce_whatsnew.php).

> The Blueberry systray menu now lets you connect or disconnect paired
> devices with a click of the mouse.

Right-clicking the Bluetooth tray icon:

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

Mint 20 Xfce also shows a different icon when a device is connected:

[image]

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to get this for a manual XFCE install in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Brandon - I don't know. The tool is `blueberry` but is not available in the Ubuntu repos afaikt, I'm in Kubuntu now and I had Xfce with this blueberry tool in Mint.  Look on the web for blueberry deb and ppa, I've found this (not tested): https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/mint_main/ulyana/main/base/blueberry, https://pkgs.org/download/blueberry. Test carefully on your own risk. It all also depends on your Ubuntu version I guess.  Mint is based on Ubuntu LTS.